# Seperating page components from feature components in lazy-loaded module

Tags: angular, performance, lazy-loading, angular5, angular-module

Working on a large single-module Angular 5 application I'm trying to divide it into multiple modules to improve maintainability and performance (lazy loading).

#### What I've done

I've created multiple modules specifically to be lazy loaded. They contain

1. The main component (page) that should render when **navigating to the route**
2. All components (pages) of the child routes
3. All the feature components (non-routeable) used in the components mentioned above.

Seeing as I need to use some of the feature components in multiple modules I'm considering either

1. Keep using my current structure and export **only** the feature components
2. Extract the feature components into a separate shared module

#### My question

Performance-wise, when a (lazy-loaded) module needs to import feature components from another module does it make a difference which of the above options I select?

Answer (score 0):

I specifically prefer feature 2 where you extract the feature components into a separate shared module, take an example of using Angular Material, you may have all your pages, both lazy-loaded and non-lazy-loaded using the about 5 or 6 of the modules repeatedly, it would be a waste of both time and resources to continuously import these modules separately into the lazy-loaded component modules, it would instead be more organized to place the modules (feature modules) into a shared module that would be reused in each lazy-loaded module.

I achieved this with a simple module as:-

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ANGULAR_MODULES,
    MATERIAL_MODULES,
    COVALENT_MODULES,
    OTHER_MODULES
  ],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [
    ANGULAR_MODULES,
    MATERIAL_MODULES,
    COVALENT_MODULES,
    OTHER_MODULES
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [SERVICES]
    };
  }
}
```

This module includes all reused modules and service. Then to use them, i just add them to my lazy-loaded module as:-

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    UsersRoutingModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [UsersComponent]
})
export class UsersModule {
}
```